# Embed a Google Sheets in a forum post

Tags: google-sheets, embed

I want to embed a Google Sheets in a forum post so that it is easily viewed by people. The spreadsheet should be read-only in the embedded status.

Any way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Information here;

[Embedding a spreadsheet](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55244)

> To embed a spreadsheet or parts of a spreadsheet in a website or a blog, you'll need to publish it first. Here's how:
>
> - Open the Share menu in the upper-right corner of the page, and select Publish as a web page.
> - In the window that appears, select which parts of the spreadsheet you'd like to publish, and click the Publish now button. A unique URL is generated.
> - Use this URL to embed the spreadsheet on your website or blog.

Although it may depend on how the admin has set up the forum (no HTML, no embedding etc.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: would you mind give me the html code to embed?

Comment: The code will be specific for your spreadsheet but in the format of; <iframe width='500' height='' frameborder='0'src='http:// spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pPwo7--7PfjIRdqjkoYfiIQ&output=html&widget=true'></iframe>